# How to run tests django rest framework tests?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning django rest framework. I wrote a simple test like this:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class ClinicTestCase(APITestCase):
    def getList(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        request = factory.get('/Clinic/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.OK)
```

my api returns empty json array for that request. What i don't know is, how do i run this test?

when i use this command:

```
python manage.py test
```

i get

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

as output. It's not written in documentation to how to run the tests.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe your test methods need to start with `test`. Change `def getList` to `def testGetList` or `def test_get_list`.

As with other python tests (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example), if methods do not start with `test` they will not be run as tests.

Comment: i'll, in 4 minutes. ^^

Comment: lol facepalm moment for me

Answer (score 0):

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

from rest_framework import status

class Portfolio_api_test(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
Your code

```
def test_your_function_name(self):
    response = self.client.get('url')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Your test function name should start with test_your_function_name